# Use OpenID Selector with Spring Security

Tags: java, openid, spring-security

How do I use an interface like http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/ for OpenID log in with Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Spring Security Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-openid) for info on configuring OpenID logins

Comment: I just read that before posting my question. I couldn't figure it out from that.

Comment: The selector seems to just pre-fill a form field with the users openid URL.  You should have that form point to your Spring security form login URL